# My iPhone app is using Facebook SDK for iOS v2.0. Will my app become broken in June 2013?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

My app on facebook has this alert:

> This app uses an outdated version of the Facebook SDK for iOS. Please
>   download the latest version: iOS SDK 3.2.1.
>
> Learn how the latest version makes it easier and faster to build great
>   mobile apps.
>
> We also provide upgrade guides to make the process as easy as
>   possible. Upgrade from SDK 2 to 3.1 and 3.1 to 3.2.
>
> Facebook will also stop supporting v2.0 of the SDK in June 2013, so
>   you are advised to upgrade to the new SDK as soon as possible.

Does this mean that v2.0 of the Facebook SDK for iOS will **stop working** in June 2013? Or, does it merely mean that Facebook will stop providing technical support and enhancements for it?

My app uses v2.0 SDK for the following:

1. Login with Facebook
2. Get list of friends
3. Send App Request to selected friends

Due to time and budget, I will not be able to have my iPhone app upgraded to version 3 until probably the end of this year. So, does this mean my iPhone app is going to be broken in June?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is recommended for you to read Facebook SDK release notes. In short, API changed & Login mechanism ( especially token management ) changed . That means your app will have chance to be broken in June.

However, stop supporting is not equal to stop service . You can ask Facebook when to stop 2.0 API service . The 2nd link should provide most programming information you require.

**Sidenote:** I upgrade my app from Facebook iOS SDK 2.0 to 3.1 in few hours. Just curious, why take you so long to perform the changes ?

Hope it helps.

Reference :

1. [Facebook iOS SDK Release Notes](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/change-log-3.x/)
2. [Upgrading from 2.0 to 3.x](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.1/)

Comment: I am not an apple developer, so I can't do the upgrade myself. I don't have an internal staff of apple developers either. My app was built by a third-party contractor, so I would need to have them do the upgrade. Budgetary constraints make this difficult to do at this time, so my app will be stuck with version 2.0 for the time being and likely well past June. I'm just hoping my app doesn't suddenly stop working or the v2.0 SDK suddenly becomes broken.

Comment: Oops. Wish you luck ( but you shouldn't rely on your luck , though ). Please accept the answer if you can.

Comment: Shivan, I appreciate your response, but I am waiting to receive a response from someone at Facebook who can comment definitively on this. I understand what is involved with doing the actual upgrade; what I need to know, from Facebook, is if it is necessary for me to upgrade by June because my app will be broken otherwise.

Comment: Facebook guys will monitor Stack Overflow, but not guaranteed they will answer this question. You'd better contact them via email.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code for your app, you can check the class reference [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/) for the latest version and see the whether the methods etc. used in your code is listed here, and whether there are any changes in how they behave / should be used.

If the classes and methods are all there, you don't need to worry. In all probability, your app should run just fine and not break.